# Moving to a house that has no current networking setup, does this diagram work?

Tags: networking, home-networking, nas, ip-camera

I'm not entirely sure how NVR and PoE camera works, but essentially, I want to view all the camera with no hassle and then save all the recorded footage onto a storage server for the NVR. Also, I want the cameras to be in its own separate network, I don't need to access it remotely or anything through the internet.

As for the networking part, I want 2 data drops in each room (just incase one drop dies for whatever reason), the brain of it all will be in my room. Ignore the device icons used, just the display is relevant.

So, my question is, does this setup work? If not, why does it not work? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with the [ANSI/TIA/EIA 570-B, Residential Telecommunications Infrastructure Standard](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&ved=0ahUKEwiTxpvW29_LAhUFuoMKHU4oBSsQFghXMAs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vyskocil.net%2Ffirma%2Fdokumenty%2Fdownload.asp%3Fid%3D156&usg=AFQjCNEQ730yEmB8aUxvAAvQSiqA_YROyg&sig2=X5zAcVaU3PYeZdB5yoZ7_g&cad=rja). Also, hubs are very outdated equipment; you should use switches instead of hubs.

Comment: if you're not sure then why not just try starting with something simple like one bedroom and if you get that working then expand it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you would need switches featuring the spanning tree protocol in order to be able to run failover.